# Is installing a Go package with 'go get' counted as cloning at GitHub?

Tags: github, go, get, clone, traffic

When a user installs a Go package with the command:

```
go get github.com/username/repositoryname/packagename
```

is this counted in the GitHub traffic as cloning?

I have a new Go repository and my GitHub account counted several clones. However I installed my own package as a test with the go get command a few times. Is this also counted as cloning or only when a user clicks on 'Clone in desktop'?

Comment: Yes, go get uses git clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `go get` clones the repository (as well as any submodules in the vendor directory if GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT is enabled.) Since the repository is being cloned, it will count in the traffic as cloning.